# solving a ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve the following ordinary differential equation:
$$\frac{f_{y}}{f}= \frac{-y}{(x^{2}-y^{2})(a(x) y^{2}+b(x))}$$ 
where $f=f(x,y)$  is a real function of two variables $x,y$  and $a=a(x)$ and $b=b(x)$   is a real functions of $x$.

My solution:

$\frac{-y}{(x^{2}-y^{2})(a(x) y^{2}+b(x))}= \frac{1}{2(a(x)x^{2}+b(x))}(\frac{-1}{x-y}+\frac{1}{x+y})-\frac{2ay}{a(x)y^{2}+b(x)}$
so,
$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2(a(x)x^{2}+b(x))}(\ln(x^{2}-y^{2}))-\ln(a(x)y^{2}+b(x))+c(x)$$
Is it correct?

Thanks.